# How get the selected text option with Selenium using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, html-select

I have this option in a web page

[screenshot html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMvUw.png)

I am trying to extract the selected text in the SELECTBOX with this code:

```
time.sleep(5)
elemento2 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "jform[cod_comune]"))))
selected_option = elemento2.first_selected_option
print(selected_option.text)
```

but I get nothing, not even errors. The text is empty.

[screenshot html code full page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3fe0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn’t use the first selected property. I recommend getting the xpath of the span tag. Then using the selenium `.text` to get the text for the field. This works for most websites

`selected_option = elemento2.text`

Basic way:

```
driver.get(url)
```

time.sleep(3)
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text

Comment: I have read many sites, but I cannot understand which XPATH to set.
The full screenshot of the page is screenshot fullpage

Comment: You want to find the xpath of a tag, right?

Comment: Yes, I can't figure out which XPATH to use

Comment: Right click on the span tag and select copy xpath

Comment: I use this {elemento2 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='jform_cod_comune_chosen']/a/span"))))    print(elemento2.text)}, but see "raise UnexpectedTagNameException(
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <span>"

Comment: You need to drop the Select

Comment: how you do it? i am not python expert

Comment: I believe I have solved with this {elemento2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='jform_cod_comune_chosen']/a/span")}